# Allow remote connection in IIS website

Tags: iis, web-deployment, remote-connection

I developed a web app, published it to the File System and try to setup the IIS to make it available to a Virtual Machine with XP and a IE8.
Everything is fine in my computer, I can see the website, but from the VM I can't and it's because the setting "Enable remote connections" in the management tab in the Site in the IIS is not checked.
The problem is that option ([view image](http://i3.iis.net/media/7181817/configuring-remote-administration-and-feature-delegation-in-iis-7-159-Fig2.jpg?cdn_id=2014-01-17-002))Manage does not appear under my Site in the IIS.
I already added all the features related with this but nothing works.
It is a asp.net application.
Any guesses?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it,
The Network Address Translation option they give in the setting will work.
Just need to access the address that both machines are using for the bridge, so you will have to go to look at the network configuration